# Dropdown is not working in Better Exposed filter

Tags: views

I am created the location taxonomy and i used the better exposed filter to expose the form but the dropdown in location from better exposed filter is not working,, so please suggest me that how to do this in drupal7. 
[image]

If i will select Bangalore then mg road within Bangalore will display, otherwise every cities are displayed like dropdown.

Comment: Using the Nested checkbox widget in BEF settings and some js you can achieve something close to what you want. Use depth classes (`bef-tree-depth-1`) to know what to show and hide.